# error al ejectuvar en terminar npm star

Tags: javascript, reactjs

a la hora de ejecutar en terminal npm star me da el siguiente error, soy nuevo en esto saben por que es?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El comando es npm start, te falto la letra T al fianl

Comment: _Start_ es "iniciar" o "inicio", _star_ es "estrella" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás escribiendo npm star en lugar de `npm start`.

Adjunto documentación:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-start

Comment: tienes razón luis, muchas gracias pero me salio de nuevo otro error

Comment: Cuantame, talvez pueda ayudarte!

Comment: me da el siguiente error:

PS C:\Users\appor\OneDrive\Escritorio\dashboard> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\appor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-04T23_02_25_506Z-debug-0.log

Comment: sabes mas o menos por que es?

Comment: Da un error al intentar correr el script, hiciste alguna modificación en el package.json?

Comment: si, hice unas modificaciones para agregar unos paquetes com un tutorial me decia

Comment: Ahí está muy posiblemente tu problema entonces, verifica la definición de script.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo luis, revisare de ahi.

Comment: A las órdenes, espero hayas podido solucionar.